# Spring and Dynamic DataSource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

I have two database structures, example:

1- MAIN_DATABASE:
USER
PASSWORD

2:
CUSTOMER DATABASE:
CUSTOMER_A
CUSTOMER_B
CUSTOMER_C

I want to access the main database and after validating the data, redirect to the customer database.

I currently use spring and configure it in applicationContext.xml

Example:

```
<bean id = "encryptionPassword" class = "utils.EncryptionPasswordSpring" />
<bean id = "dataSource" class = "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method = "close">
<property name = "driverClass" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name = "user" value = "user" />
<property name = "password" value = "123456" />
<property name = "jdbcUrl" value = "jdbc: mysql: // localhost / testdb? useSSL = false" />
</bean>
```

Any example, suggestion? Thanks.